# Compile *.cs file during runtime and access member

Tags: c#

Is it possible to compile a cs file during run time so I can access it like a normal class?

In practice I read out a text file and store its information in a class structure. Afterwards I need to access class members within my application.

What I did by now: I compiled the cs file and created a dll using this example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.generateexecutable.aspx

I changed it to:

```
String exeName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.dll",
                System.Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                sourceFile.Name.Replace(".", "_"));

cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
cp.OutputAssembly = Name;
cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
```

So what now?

edit:
will this help me:

```
[DllImport("srec_struct_cs.dll", SetLastError = true)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can load the assembly using one of the [AppDomain.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.load.aspx) overloads.

Comment: so far ok, I now used domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap() to pass the dll path but what does he expect as type (2. parameter)?

Comment: @wandermeise: you could always look at the documentation.  It depends upon which overload you are using, the two parameter, `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string, string)` version appears to take the assembly name and the type name.

Comment: the type of what? I wanna access a class, which type is that? I dont get it!

Comment: @wanderameise: 'Type' is a generic term for refering to classes, structs, enums and other object-oriented constructs that the language provides.  So, if you are creating a class then by 'type' read 'class'.  If you are creating a struct then by 'type' read 'struct', &c.